# Electric field/intensity for complex envelope

Tags: electric-fields, complex-numbers, intensity

When calculating the propagation of a pulse I can either use an envelope-based or a carrier-based approach. For the carrier-based approach I can define my (focused) pulse with the central frequency $\omega_0$ as
$$E(r, t, z = 0) = E_0\exp\left(-\frac{r^2}{w_0^2}-i\frac{k_0r^2}{2f}+\left(\frac{t}{t_0}\right)^2\right)\cdot\exp\left(-i\omega_0t\right)$$
To calculate the envelope of this pulse, I can apply the Hilbert transformation and use the definition
$$E_m(r, t, z)\equiv Re\left(E_a(r, t, z)\right)$$
which then can be used to calculate the intensity with a constant $c$ as
$$I_m(r, t, z) = c Re\left( E_a(r, t, z)\right)^2$$
Nevertheless, when transitioning to an envelope-based approach, I lose the part $\exp(-i\omega_0t)$, and therefore the approach shown above does not work anymore. Thus, now I am a bit unsure if my real field still can be defined as
$$E_r(r, t, z)=Re\left(E(r, t, z)\right)$$
and the intensity correspondingly
$$I(r, t, z) = c\left(Re\left(E(r, t, z)\right)\right)^2$$
or if I have to take the absolute value
$$E_r(r, t, z) = \sqrt{Re\left(E\right)^2+Im\left(E\right)^2}$$
and the intensity
$$I_r(r, t, z) = c\left(Re\left(E\right)^2+Im\left(E\right)^2\right)$$
Which of those definitions is correct?

Answer (score 0):

$E$ field oscillates at the frequency $\omega$ while the intensity does not. So, $I\propto|E|^2$ because absolute value "removes" the $e^{i\omega t}$ part, and Re and Im do not. This holds for complex fields regardless of how you define your pulse profile.